# Node.js - fs.stat throws ENOENT The operation completed successfully

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to follow episode 3 of nodetuts.com.  Also, I'm using the newest (unstable) version of node - node.exe, version 0.5.2.  Here is my code, I've been beating my head against a wall with this error practically all day.  Is it just a windows thing?

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var file_path = __dirname + '\\me.jpg';
console.log('serving: '+file_path);
fs.stat(file_path, function(err, stat){

    if (err) throw err;

    http.createServer(function(request,response){

        response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type':'image/jpeg'
        });

        fs.readFile(file_path, function(err, file_content){

            response.write(file_content);
            response.end();
        });

    }).listen(8000);
})
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The 0.5.x is buggy on Windows. You can do

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/file.txt', callback);
```

I believe 0.6 will fix these problems. :)

Comment: Instead of the 'callback', I should place in the callback function (not attach it to a var) correct?  I think I did this wrong and the results are still the same...  Thanks though.

Comment: The problem isn't the way you code nor some syntax. The problem lies within the ´fs´ and actually even deeper in the network code. We need to wait for the 0.6 version or you can get it to work by using the `__dirname` as I have shown above.

Comment: 0.6 still has that problem. I had that when installing expressjs with npm (Windows).

Comment: Really? I have not tried, but it should still work with the `__dirname` trick (i.e., make the path relative, not absolute and it also must begin with the dirname).

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using node v0.5.x for now as it's considered unstable. Use **v0.4.x**. If you used the git to grab node, do this:

```
cd /path/to/your/local/node/git
git checkout v0.4.12
make && sudo make install
```

Comment: For some reason make just... doesn't do anything.  It's been using up 50% of my CPU for about 3 hours now.  Go figure.  (That's the main reason I've been using the .exe)

Comment: @dresende: He is using Windows, not *nix.

Comment: Yeah.. I noticed. Windows is still buggy, you should probably use the .exe or compile and use on cygwin (yak!). Or wait for 0.6 which will come out soon.