# Hexo deploy on github

Tags: node.js, github-pages, hexo

I tried to deploy the **Hexo** on my GithubPage.

The generate process looks fine, but error happens when I deploy it on my GithubPage.

Here's the deployment part in **_config.yml**:

```
# Deployment
## Docs: https://hexo.io/docs/deployment.html
deploy:
type: git
repo: https://github.com/ZhangYuef/ZhangYuef.github.io.git
# branch: Hexo
```

Generate

[image]

Deployment
[image]

So what's going on there?
Thx for help!  :)

Answer (score 0):

The context you provided in the question is not sufficient...

But according to invalid chars on the screenshot, I suppose that your Chinese file path may be the cause.

References:

- [Node JS Error: ENOENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047094/node-js-error-enoent)
- [Why does ENOENT mean "No such file or directory"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902828/why-does-enoent-mean-no-such-file-or-directory/19902850#19902850)

Answer (score 0):

try to update the _config.yml like this:

```
deploy:
  type: git
  repository: https://github.com/fakeYanss/fakeYanss.github.io.git
  branch: master
```

yaml is very very very strict, and indent is important!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what reason causing this error. 
Check your environment whether these things have been set up.
I think it might be your config type is wrong.

- npm install **hexo-deployer-git** --save
- git repository settings like

`deploy:
  - type: git
    repo: git@github.com:xxx.git
    branch: master
  - type: git
    repo: git@github.com:xxx.git
    branch: src
    extend_dirs: /
    ignore_hidden: false
    ignore_pattern:
        public: .`

By this way, you can not only deploy your blog, but also backup your blog files, which you can use the command `git pull` to get the blog files on another machine. 
- set up your ssh 

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "yourEmail@icloud.com"
ssh-agent -s
chmod id_rsa 600
ssh-add id_rsa
(you need to add the id_rsa.pub to the github's deployer key)
ssh -T git@github.com`

- sometimes it maybe you have several gits, make deployer confused.
  Try delete `.git` directory and make sure there is no any git in other directories.
- encoding. It could be the encoding is different. In my case, I make all the files belong to `UTF-8`.
- By the way, it could be your files' error.try `npm install hexo-server --save` and `hexo server` to detect whether the website can be deployed.
  (http://localhost:4000/xx)