# How to fix Node/NPM errors: ELIFECYCLE and ENOENT

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts, npm-start

I am trying to setup a site to receive bitcoin transactions where the users address is generated off there user id.

I am using someone elses source code (already tried contacting creator, wouldn't help me) and am unable to get any help anywhere as its a couple years old and has no interest.

Basically whenever I type `npm start` I get an error that references a line of my package.json file that I don't understand how it's wrong.

I can't get this site to let me paste my code, so have an image.
[image: Error Code]

and my package.json: [package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pH6yq.png)

Just an update:
The source of my package that I am trying to run is from [here:](https://github.com/moneypot/bustabit-depositor)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the ELIFECYCLE Node.js error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744964/what-does-the-elifecycle-node-js-error-mean)

Comment: Well, I know what it means, but I can't figure out why its happening/what the error in my script is, any help would be apreciated

Comment: have you tried `npm install`? might be caused of new component being added

Comment: I did try that, if you want to check my code, the error appears here: ` start script 'env $(cat .env | xargs) forever start daemon.js `

Comment: Maybe because of the previous error [`ENOENT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047094/node-js-error-enoent)? cat: .env No such file or directory
env: 'forever': No such file or directory

Comment: I am very new to all of this, would you happen to have suggestions for an edit? I am trying to reference a config.env file in the same directory as the package

Comment: Probably add info about where you get the package/component? Example: "I get it from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-notifier)"

Also, you could try to ask in their GitHub issue if there is one since they would be more familiar about it.

Comment: Ok, will update my question with more info. Also already tried posting on the GitHub issue, its a fairly niche type of project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found

wasn't defining the path of my .env file.

```
env $(cat ./config.env | xargs)
```