# How to fix 'Error: ENOENT' in node.js if the file and the requirement was deleted?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I recently changed the event handler dor my discord bot and I get this error.

I edited all the files so I don`t get any error but now I get this error and it does not say where the error takes place

````js
(node:9356) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\user1\Documents\GitHub\MYSQL_TEST\utils\events'
(node:9356) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9356) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node JS Error: ENOENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047094/node-js-error-enoent)

Comment: It does say where the error took place `C:\Users\user1\Documents\GitHub\MYSQL_TEST\utils\events`