# Error: Command failed with exit code ENOENT

Tags: android, ios, cordova, platform

I'm a first time user of Cordova/Phonegap. I have it set up but I can't add any platforms. This is the error I get. I'm at a loss. I'm on Windows 8 running the latest Node.js and Cordova.

```
$ cordova platform add ios
Creating ios project...
Error: C:\Users\[me]\.cordova\lib\ios\cordova\3.5.0\bin\create: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\su
perspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:808:12)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: ENOENT is usually a file not found error, [information here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681407/node-js-fs-stat-throws-enoent-the-operation-completed-successfully)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on Windows 8? You can't add platform iOS then, this only works on a Mac environment.

Comment: I was getting the same error trying to add Android. Realised it was because the Android SDK wasn't installed. And yes, as you correctly pointed out, I won't be able to install the Apple SDK on Windows.